# Include custom cmdlets in Visual Studio PowerShell window

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, visual-studio-2015, nuget, powershell-cmdlet

My company is using Visual Studio 2015 which has the very practical PowerShell Interactive Window and also the NuGet Paket Manager Console, which is basically a PowerShell host.

We would like use some of our own cmdlets in one of these windows. Is there any way I can configure to load them 'automatically', similar to the auto-loaded user profile in PowerShell? Preferably based on the currently opened solution, if possible.

Please consider: Using the regular PowerShell profile will not work, because it is not loaded in these windows. Also, even if it did work, this would be a solution on a per user basis only.

(Note: These cmdlets are script cmdlets, but I think/hope this won't make a big difference.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start your powershell interactive / Nuget package manager window and type `$profile`. You'll see where your profile is defined. You can then add your own cmdlets to that profile. See [this article](http://www.xavierdecoster.com/post/2012/06/04/installing-commands-into-the-nuget-powershell-profile) for more information.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know there was a "Nuget profile"